# How to upgrade plan in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

How to upgrade plan in Stripe for a customer already having a plan, but suddenly wanting to upgrade to a new plan?

```
Stripe::setApiKey(Yii::app()->params['secret_key']);
  $cus = Stripe_Customer::retrieve("cus_7SR4oHy8NwS1DE");
  $subscription = $cus->subscriptions->retrieve("sub_7SR4kA30QUQTE9"); 
  $subscription->plan = sliver; 
  $subscription->save();
```

With the code above,
when a customer already has a silver plan subscription it's working fine, but when I change to the gold plan it shows the error below.

```
Can't combine currencies on a single customer. This customer has had a subscription, coupon, or invoice item with currency usd
```

When users upgrade plan, can I update subscriptions_current_period_end and subscriptions_current_period_start?

Comment: Are your silver and gold plans in the same currency?

Comment: the error code would indicate that the new plan is not in USD currency

Comment: but i didn't mention any currency when change plan then why its showing error .is it possible to change plan because my both plans are same currency GBP Not USD currency.

Comment: That error is saying the current subscription is USD not GBP

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, once a subscription or an invoice is created for a customer, they are "locked" into that currency. It isn't possible to create a new subscription or update an existing subscription to switch to a plan in a different currency for that customer.

The only easy solution here would be to ask your customer for his card details again and [create a new customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) so that you can subscribe them to a plan in a different currency.

There are other [options involving Connect platform](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!topic/api-discuss/nH27lKuQA6g), but they may require additional elaborate effort.

Comment: But am updating existing subscription to switch to a plan in a same currency not different currency for that customer.